# Элементы и граница Grid layout

Tags: javascript, css

Выходят дочерние элементы за границу родительского блока. Все перепробовал ничего не помогло.

**Как добиться результата как на картинке при помощи Grid-Css?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main_block');
let child_block = document.querySelector('.child_block');
            
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
let newBlock = document.createElement('div'); 
child_block.prepend(newBlock);
newBlock.className = 'block';
newBlock.innerHTML = 'Слово'
}
```

```css
.main_block{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 100%; 
padding:10px;
margin:50px;
border:1px solid black;
}

.child_block{
display:grid;
grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.block{
display: inline-block;  
border:1px solid black;
font-size:18px;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "main_block">
<div class = "child_block">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите лишние правила у `.child_block`, которые вызывают такое отображение

Почему так:

1. Вы прописали нужные правила родительскому блоку, а стили у `.child_block` перекрывают нужные. К примеру, вам нужен перенос переполняющего контейнер элемента на новую строку, вместо стандартного значения `grid-auto-flow: row`, вы прописали `grid-auto-flow: column`, что помешало вам с переносом.
2. Если оставить `display: grid` у `.child_block` без указания `grid-template` у вас элементы растянутся на весь контейнер`

[grid-auto-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main_block');
let child_block = document.querySelector('.child_block');
            
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
let newBlock = document.createElement('div'); 
child_block.prepend(newBlock);
newBlock.className = 'block';
newBlock.innerHTML = 'Слово'
}
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_block{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%; 
  padding:10px;
  margin:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.block{
  display: inline-block;  
  border:1px solid black;
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "main_block">
<div class = "child_block">

</div>
</div>
```